# changing activities of android using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

i am starting to make a game on android using phone gap. i want to switch between different layouts (like to change activities). as there is no activity in phonegap it extend Droidgap. any answer will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap basically uses Android Webview to display all activities. Just create different HTML pages and make links between them, you should then be able to navigate among all activities.